# How to display numbers in calculator, using TKinter in Python?

Tags: python, math, tkinter, calculator

this is my code:

```
from Tkinter import*

calculator = Tk()
calculator.title('Calcualtor')
calculator.geometry('300x325')

screen = Frame(calculator, bd=2, width=250, height=25, relief=SUNKEN)
buttons = Frame(calculator, bd=2, width=250, height=200)
screen.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=25, pady=25)
buttons.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=25)

def appear():
    results.insert(0, "0")
    return

numbers=["7", "4", "1", "8", "5", "2", "9", "6", "3"]
for index in range(9):
   Button(buttons, bg="White", text=numbers[index], width=5, height=2, command=appear).grid(padx=5, pady=5, row=index%3, column=index/3) 

zero= Button(buttons, bg="White", text="0", width=5, height=2)
zero.grid(padx=5, pady=5, column=1, row=3)

functions=["-", "+", "*", "/"]
for index in range(4):
    Button(buttons, bg="White", text=functions[index], width=5, height=2).grid(padx=5, pady=5, row=index%4, column=3) 

equals= Button(buttons, bg="White", text="=", width=5, height=2)
equals.grid(ipadx=10, pady=5, row=5, column=1)

numbers = StringVar()
results = Entry(screen, textvariable=numbers, width=30)
results.pack()

calculator.mainloop()
```

---

The calculator looks good, but I need help making it display a number as a button is pressed. As you can see in my function, right now it displays "0" every time a button is pressed, instead of the corresponding number. HELP please. I haven't started figuring out how to make it do the actual math, but if you can help on that too, that'd be great!

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a closure which returns the associated number of a button. Change your `appear` function to this:

```
def appear(x):
    #return an anonymous function which appends x to the "result" textentry
    return lambda: results.insert(END, x)
```

And then change the definition of your Buttons like this:

```
numbers = ["7", "4", "1", "8", "5", "2", "9", "6", "3"]
for index in range(9):
    n = numbers[index]
    Button(buttons, text=n, command=appear(n), ...).grid(...)
```

This way each Button gets its own function which appends the correct number.

In Python, a function is just another object. The `command` argument of the `Button` class takes a function (or any other callable thing like a class) as an argument which is called when the button is pressed. The `lambda` keyword creates an anonymous function which we pass to the class. The appear method defined above is analogue to this:

```
def appear(x):
    #create a new function that displays x in the text entry and return it
    def show_x():
        results.insert(END, x)
    return show_x
```

We cannot inline the lambda in this case:

```
#THIS DOESN'T WORK AS EXPECTED:
for index in range(9):
    n = numbers[index]
    f = lambda: results.insert(END, n)
    Button(..., command = f, ...)
```

This won't work because `n` is a local variable that changes with each iteration of the loop and is looked up during execution of the function `f` - meaning it will always hold the last value in this case. We need to create a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) for the value, which we do in the `appear` function.

Comment: Hey, good catch. I think I'm just gonna delete my answer, since when I fixed it, it looked *very* similar to yours.

Comment: @DianaMC, the "append" was a typo. The insertion at the front was due to the `0` as the first argument to insert, I copied this from your appear function without thinking about it... change it to the Tkinter constant END to append to the end of the entry.

Comment: @l4mpi so my teacher wants me to be able to explain why lambda works. Do you think you can give me a brief explanation?

Comment: @DianaMC, I added an explanaion if you're still interested.